# C++ how to build iterator for vector of vectors

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a two-dimensional array which I have implemented as a `std::vector` of `std::vector`s, like so:

```
struct Cell
{};

struct Column
{ std::vector<Cell*> m_column; };

struct Grid
{ std::vector<Column> m_grid; }
```

I want to build an input iterator class for Grid, so that you can do this...

```
for (const auto cell : grid)
    cell->doSomething();
```

...and use other STL algorithms. But I'm not sure how to make the iterator increment function.

Here's what I have so far:

```
struct Grid
{
    std::vector<Column> m_grid;

    struct ConstIterator
    {
        using value_type = const Cell*;
        using reference = const Cell*&;
        using pointer = const Cell**;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;

        reference operator* () { return curr; }

        ConstIterator& operator++ () { incrementAcrossGrid(); return *this; }
        ConstIterator operator++(int) { const auto temp(*this); incrementAcrossGrid(); return temp; }

        bool operator== (const ConstIterator& that) { return curr == that.curr; }
        bool operator!= (const ConstIterator& that) { return !(*this == that); }

        void incrementAcrossGrid()
        {
            // ???
        }

        const Cell* curr;
    };

    ConstIterator begin() const { return { m_grid.front().m_column.front() }; }
    ConstIterator end() const { return { m_grid.back().m_column.back() + 1 }; } // Is there a better way to get the end?
};
```

As you can see, I'm not sure what to put inside `incrementIterator()`. It's easy to increment it until it reaches the end of its column, but I don't know how to point it from the bottom of one column to the top of the next.

It might be that I'm taking entirely the wrong approach, so all suggestions are welcome (including Boost libraries, etc.). The important thing is that I need to be able to use Grid::begin() and Grid::end() to iterate over the Cells.

Comment: Tip: you need to store *two* iterators in your iterator class. One for iteratating over `std::vector<Column>` and one for iterating over `std::vector<Cell*>` in current `Column`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The basic idea is to keep two iterators inside your custom one:

```
struct Iterator {
    reference operator* () { 
        return *cell_iterator;
    }

    Iterator& operator++() {
        if (++cell_iterator == col_iterator->m_column.end()) {
            ++col_iterator;
            cell_iterator = col_iterator->m_column.begin();
        }
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(const Iterator& that) const {
        return col_iterator == that.col_iterator && 
               cell_iterator == that.cell_iterator;
    }
    
    std::vector<Cell*>::iterator  cell_iterator;
    std::vector<Column>::iterator col_iterator;
};

auto Grid::begin() -> Iterator {
    return Iterator{m_grid.begin()->m_column.begin(), m_grid.begin()};
}
```

This is only an idea. You should think about how to represent `Grid::end()` iterator correctly and make necessary changes to `operator++()`. When `col_iterator` hits `m_grid.end()`, you can no longer dereference it to get next `cell_iterator`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It would have taken me a long time to come up with this by myself.

I'm not very clear on what the `std::vector::iterator` part is. In my code, I had used a raw pointer instead to point to the Cell. Is `std::vector::iterator` a convenience or a necessity here? I'm asking because in reality I'm not using `std::vector` but [JUCE::OwnedArray] (https://docs.juce.com/master/classOwnedArray.html), and this doesn't seem to have an equivalent `iterator` sub-class. Is there a possibility of finding a workaround, or should I just use `std::vector` instead of `JUCE::OwnedArray`?

Comment: @LiamGoodacre, it's just a convenience. Iteration over contiguous storage like `std::vector` can always be performed with plain pointers. `OwnedArray::begin` and `OwnedArray::end` return `ObjectClass*`. Just replace `std::vector<T>::iterator` with `T*`. Note: not `Cell*`, but `Cell**` if `m_column` indeed holds pointers, and not `Cell` objects themselves.

Comment: I think the logic for `operator++` is a bit off. We first check if we're at the end of the current column and if not, go one further in it and return that; that might be the end! I have an `Image` class which has `Line`s of `Pixel`s, so for myself I corrected this to `if (++pixel_iter == line_iter->end()) { line_iter++; pixel_iter = line_iter->begin(); }`. Definitely was reading one over each line and ended up with a segfault. Doing it this way allow you to implement `MyClass::end()` as `return Iterator{ line.end()->begin(), line.end() };`.

Comment: @zaep You're right, the code in my answer is wrong. But one problem with your approach is that when you hit the last `Pixel` in the last `Line`, then the next application of `operator++` will set `line_iter` to the past-the-end iterator and doing `->begin()` on it is undefined behaviour. You can't do `line.end()->begin()` even if you never dereference the resulting iterator.

Comment: I've made a correction about past-the-end cell iterator, but the problem about representing past-the-last elements remains to be solved.

Comment: @Evg thanks for letting me know, I wasn't aware of that. It's seemed to work for me so far, but I'll look into cleaning it up.

Comment: @zaep It might work the same way writing unallocated memory might work. But if you enable debugging iterators (e.g. with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` in GCC), you'll get an exception.